# how to include signature in outlook javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to create an email using javamail where i can attach many files and also configure the body message , destination and many settings... at the end i save this email in a temp file to use it in outlook 2016 where i can now open outlook and pass the eml file using outlook command line with switch /eml. 
The problem is is a try to attach one file with outlook using the switch /a, i can see the signature the footer of the body message but when i use the created eml file i can not see any signature.

what i tried to do is to load the pre-saved signature in roaming folder from different format (htm, rtf and txt)  with txt file there is no problem and can put it inside the message in eml file but using rtf i cannot visualize the content as i see in ms word, using the htm file  the images (if exist) still not visible.

I'm wondering how i can use one of the two (html or rtf file) to include the signature in the bottom of the body message automatically. 
Hope that someone already worked on the same subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mainly in the path's image included in the htm file, so I parsed the original path with the absolute one, so i can visualize the image correctly

```
public static String getSignature() throws IOException {
    String content ="";
    String appDataPath = System.getenv("APPDATA")+"\\Microsoft\\Signatures\\"; 
    System.out.println(appDataPath);
    File folder = new File(appDataPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      File file = listOfFiles[i];

      if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".htm")) {
            content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file , "windows-1252");
            content =content.replaceAll("src=\"", "src=\"" +appDataPath.replace("\\", "/"));
      } 
    } 

    return  content; 
}
```

Then I retrieve the content and I put it inside the message that I want to send.

```
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    body.setDisposition(MimePart.INLINE);
    body.setContent(signature, "text/html");
    mmp.addBodyPart(body);
```

I added some enhancement on the code:

```
public static String[] getSignature() throws IOException {
    String content = "";
    String appDataPath =System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\Microsoft\\Signatures\\";
    System.out.println(appDataPath);
    File folder = new File(appDataPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();  

    String imagePath ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".htm")) {
            content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "windows-1252");
            content = content.replaceAll("src=\"", "src=\"" + appDataPath.replace("\\", "/"));   

        }else if(file.isDirectory()){
            File[] listOfHtmlFiles = file.listFiles();
            for (File f : listOfHtmlFiles) { 
                if(Files.probeContentType(f.toPath()).contains("image")) {
                      imagePath = f.getPath();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new String[]{content,imagePath};
}
```

i this new code i retrieve the signature from html and the image path from html files folders.

Then i created image an image as joint file ( attached to the email) 
then i modify src in the signature as follow :

```
        MimeBodyPart imgBP = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(imgPath);
    imgBP.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    imgBP.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
    mmp.addBodyPart(imgBP);

    signature = signature.replaceFirst("(src=)([\"|\'])(.*)([\"|\'])", 
    "$1$2cid:image$4"); 
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    body.setDisposition(MimePart.INLINE);
    body.setContent("<br><br><br>" + signature, "text/html");
    mmp.addBodyPart(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a snapshot of the signature and save it in a particular directory and send a HTML email by inserting the image . You can find something [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm) on how you can send inline HTML images in the message body. Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem is the signature is different from machine to another, so it's outlook account has its own signature saved in roaming folder, so my aim is to load html or rtf file as signature , taking snapshot is not practical solution. Thanks for your proposal